# How to combine input fiters for numberdecimal EditText?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an app with single numberdecimal `EditText`. I have done 2 input filters for that EditText. I want to combine these input filters, because one of them isn't working:
I want to make that the user cannot enter a value greater than `120.0`. 
Example:

> User can input 1, 2.3, 23, 45.7, 89.6, 119.9, 120.0 etc. 
>   User can't input 3.34, 45.76, 89.652, 120.00, 121.00 etc.

But this code allow user to enter as many digits before decimal point, as he want:(

Code of my input filters:

```
    editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {new InputFilterMinMax(1,120)});
    editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {new DecimalDigitsInputFilter(1)});

    public class DecimalDigitsInputFilter implements InputFilter {

    private final int decimalDigits;

    /**
     * Constructor.
     *
     * @param decimalDigits maximum decimal digits
     */
    public DecimalDigitsInputFilter(int decimalDigits) {
        this.decimalDigits = decimalDigits;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source,
                               int start,
                               int end,
                               Spanned dest,
                               int dstart,
                               int dend) {


        int dotPos = -1;
        int len = dest.length();
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            char c = dest.charAt(i);
            if (c == '.' || c == ',') {
                dotPos = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (dotPos >= 0) {

            // protects against many dots
            if (source.equals(".") || source.equals(","))
            {
                return "";
            }
            // if the text is entered before the dot
            if (dend <= dotPos) {
                return null;
            }
            if (len - dotPos > decimalDigits) {
                return "";
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    }

    public class InputFilterMinMax implements InputFilter {

    private int min, max;

    public InputFilterMinMax(int min, int max) {
        this.min = min;
        this.max = max;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
        try {
            int input = Integer.parseInt(dest.toString() + source.toString());
            if (isInRange(min, max, input))
                return null;
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) { }
        return "";
    }

    private boolean isInRange(int a, int b, int c) {
        return b > a ? c >= a && c <= b : c >= b && c <= a;
    }
   }
```

Please, define me how to create a combined filter, that work with edittext as I want

Comment: 3.34 < 120.0, why use can not input 3.34?

Comment: @PhanVanLinh because he can input only numbers with one decimal or without them, such as 1, 2.3, 23, 45.7, 89.6, 119.9, 120.0

Comment: @PhanVanLinh can you help me for creating one filter? If I am having these 2 filters, i can write as many number before decimal point as I want.      Example: 12346832.0 23456789.5, 3456.7, 55684.9.